# Android SMS Notification Generate

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create a custom solution, to notify on SMS Receive.
I found some solutions on Stackoverflow, but they are not working, can anybody help me, where i am wrong. Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"Message Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("SMS Received");


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and Manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".IncomingSmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
        android:priority="1000">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class IncomingSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String messageBody = "no data";
            String messageFrom = "no data";

            for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                messageFrom = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            }

            Log.d("Sms:", messageBody + " " + messageFrom);
        }
    }
}
```